Product of manifold with boundary
I have a question about the Cartesian product of two manifold with boundary $M$ and $N$. I am working with topological manifolds instead of smooth manifold. I know that $M\times N$ is still a manifold with boundary, but I'm not sure if I have the right proof. The point that troubles me is to see that the intersection $\partial M \times \partial N$ is also boundary of the product manifold (not the topological boundary but manifold boundary), i.e. every point in the intersection is still homeomorphic to some open subsets of halfspace $H_{n+m}:=\{x\in R_{n+m} \:\:| \:\pi_{n+m}(x)\geq0\}$, here $\pi$ denotes the projection to the corresponding axis.
This is not entirely trivial because for points in $\partial M \times \partial N$, they have open neighborhood that is homeomorphic to some open sets in the quadrant space $Q_{n+m}:=\{x\in R_{n+m} \:\:| \:\pi_{n+m-1}(x),\pi_{n+m}(x)\geq0\}$ (Axes are renamed for convenience). So the problem boils down to showing $Q_{n+m}$ is homeomorphic to $H_{n,m}$, which I am not sure if it is true (maybe there is other way to show there is some open neighborhood of the points in the halfspace that I am not aware of).
I am guessing the map $F(x_0,\cdots,x_{n+m})=(x_0,\cdots,x_{n+m-2},r\text{cos}(\frac{1}{2}\text{atan2}(\frac{x_{n+m}}{x_{n+m-1}})),r\text{sin}(\frac{1}{2}\text{atan2}(\frac{x_{n+m}}{x_{n+m-1}})))$ is the desired homeomorphism , here $r = \sqrt{x_{n+m}^2+x_{n+m-1}^2}$. It is a continuous function as the components are continuous, and by characteristic property it is a continuous function. I guess it is bijective and the inverse is given by $(y_0,\cdots,y_{n+m})\mapsto (y_0,\cdots,r\text{cos}(2\text{atan2}(\frac{y_{n+m}}{y_{n+m-1}})),r\text{sin}(2\text{atan2}(\frac{y_{n+m}}{y_{n+m-1}})))$ which is also continuous.
Is this the correct approach?

The statement is false. The square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ is not a smooth manifold with boundary; it’s a more general beast, called a smooth manifold with corners.

Oh, here I am not working with the smooth structure, but just working topological manifold.

Ok got it; just be sure to clarify in the post and edit your tags.

A lot of this is just indexing issues, which I don’t feel like getting into. I see some arctans and sines and cosines which seem to be on the right track. Anyway, start by concretely showing $[0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}\times [0,\infty)$. The rest is just induction/more notation. See also this answer, which essentially confirms the train of thought.

Thank you for your comment, my idea is just halving the angle, and I think this is enough.

Yup, doubling/halving the angle respectively.
